# Oracle SQL Function in WHERE clause takes longer to run than in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Really this is two related questions

**Question:** Why would a query run faster with a function in a select clause than in the where clause

**Question:** Why would an inline view take longer when moving the where clause from the inline view to the outer query.

I'm not going to dump the entire query since it has columns and tables related to my work, but this is basically it. If you need a working example I will write a SQLFiddle that is similar to what I'm doing.

**Run Time: 117s,
Returns: 93 records**

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM my_table
WHERE [CONDITIONS...]
 and my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) = 'Y';
```

If I were to run the function by itself with what would be the bind var and what would be one of the COL1 values it would take .06s. So,

```
SELECT my_package.my_function(VAL1, VAL2) FROM DUAL;
```

So I rewrote the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
   FROM my_table
   WHERE [CONDITIONS...]
 ) temp_tbl
 WHERE my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) = 'Y';
```

**Run Time: 116s,
Returns: 93 records**

The query without the function takes ~3 seconds to run, but it doesn't make sense that a function that takes .06s for 93 records would take ~116s to run.

I tried seeing what happens if I moved the function to the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) as fn_indc
   FROM my_table
   WHERE [CONDITIONS...]
 ) temp_tbl
 WHERE fn_indc = 'Y';
```

When I run the inline view query it takes ~3 seconds to run. When I add the `WHERE fn_indc = 'Y';` it takes ~116 seconds to run. Why would moving the function from the WHERE to the SELECT matter? Comparison of CHAR does not take that long to perform. Also, if I made an inline view that retrieved the value from the function and performed my where conditions in the outer query, what would cause this to run longer?

Comment: Did you look at the explain plans for any of these cases?

Comment: How many times is the function actually being executed?  The optimizer is free to evaluate predicates in whatever order it expects to be most efficient.  My guess is that when the query is slow the query plan involves calling the function many more than 93 times.  When the query is fast, the query plan involves trimming the result set to 93 rows before calling the function.  You'd need to provide query plans to verify that guess.  Theoretically, any of these queries would probably be capable of producing either the fast plan or the slow plan at any point in time.

Comment: What's confusing is that the explain plan tells me that the cost is less for the query that has the function in the WHERE clause. The cost for `WHERE my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) = 'Y';` is 1. Wouldn't having the function in the outer query force the optimizer to run the inline view first?

Comment: The answer is, "It's just one of those things".  Compliments for determining a workaround that makes your query perform better.

Comment: @DanBracuk does this mean I skipped my yearly ritual of sacrificing an intern to the Oracle gods?

Comment: it would be easier to answer your question if you would post execution plans for both queries... Comparing the run time might be very inaccurate - higher/lower load, cached/uncached table/index data, etc.

Comment: what is your goal - to understand why is it happening or to make it work faster?

Comment: do you have a function-based index for  my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) ?

Comment: @enigmasck - My wild guess is that the statistics on your function make the optimizer think it is much less expensive to execute and/or much more selective than it actually is so it thinks that it would be more efficient to execute it more times rather than doing some other check more times.  My guess is that if you associate appropriate statistics Oracle will start picking the faster plan https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4006.htm

Comment: @JustinCave this is exactly it. Basically other predicates were filtering the query after the function ran. So the function was filtering a couple thousand records and the other conditions filtered it even further down. associating stats on my function made the other conditions execute first. If you want to answer this question I will accept it. I'd rather not answer my own question since all the heavy lifting was done by everyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many times is the function being executed in each case?

Without seeing query plans, I would wager that the query runs quickly when the other predicates are evaluated first, paring the result set down as much as possible before the function is called.  When the function is only called 93 times (plus however many additional executions are required for the rows that aren't eliminated by any other predicate) the query runs quickly.  On the other hand, if the function is called earlier in the query plan, it will be called many more times--potentially once for every row in the table and the query will return much more slowly.  You could validate this by looking at the query plans or using some instrumentation to measure exactly how many times the function is called in the different cases.

The Oracle optimizer is free to evaluate predicates in whatever order it deems appropriate based on statistics.  It is possible that rewriting a query will cause the optimizer to choose a different plan that is better or worse.  But tomorrow, the optimizer is perfectly free to change its mind and to use the slower plan for any of the variants that you posted.  Of course, Murphy being the law of the land, the optimizer is likely to wait for the worst possible time to decide to flip the query plan on you when it will cause you the most pain and suffering.

If the optimizer thinks that both the fast plan and the slow plan are roughly equally costly, that probably implies that it thinks that the function is either much less expensive to evaluate than it actually is or much more selective than it actually is.  The best way to correct that mistaken belief is to [associate statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4006.htm) with the function.  This lets you tell the optimizer how expensive the query is and how selective it is.  That, in turn, lets the optimizer make better estimates and makes it likely that it will pick the more efficient plan regardless of how you write the query (and makes it much less likely that the plan will change for the worse in the future).

Now, you can also cheat a bit by writing the query in a way that prevents the optimizer from merging the predicate either by using hints or by putting something in the inline view that prevents the predicate from being pushed.  One old trick is to throw a `rownum` in to the inline view.  Of course, it is possible that some future version of the optimizer will be smart enough to figure out that `rownum` isn't doing anything here and can safely be removed.  And you'd need to leave a nice long comment for the next person who comes along and wonders why you put a `rownum` in a query when you're not doing anything with it.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, rownum
   FROM my_table
   WHERE [CONDITIONS...]
 ) temp_tbl
 WHERE my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't give us much information, so i will guess...

the following query does most probably make use of some indexes so it runs faster compared to FTS (Full Table Scan):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) as fn_indc
   FROM my_table
   WHERE [CONDITIONS...]
 ) temp_tbl
 WHERE fn_indc = 'Y';
```

so it would access 'my_table' by corresponding index(es), then it would apply [my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1)] function only to rows belonging to the result-set (i.e. that got through the filtering)

If you didn't define function-based index oracle is not able to use indexes for the queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
   FROM my_table
   WHERE [CONDITIONS...]
 ) temp_tbl
 WHERE my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) = 'Y';
```

so it does the following:
1. FTS (Full Table Scan) for my_table
2. apply filter on each row: my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) = 'Y'

PS if you would change your function, so that it would return the [:bind_var] instead of expecting it as a parameter then you could build function-based index and make use of it as follows:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM my_table
WHERE [CONDITIONS...]
 and my_package.my_function(COL1) = :bind_var;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering part of my question:

> Question: Why would an inline view take longer when moving the where
>   clause from the inline view to the outer query.

This is because nested queries are joined as an outer join by the sql optimizer. So what I was trying to accomplish by having the other conditions run before the function was undone by the sql optimizer. If I wanted to force the sql optimizer to run my inline view first I can add `rownum >= 1`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
   FROM my_table
   WHERE [CONDITIONS...]
      and rownum >= 1
 ) temp_tbl
 WHERE my_package.my_function(:bind_var, COL1) = 'Y';
```

https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/optimizer_transformations_subquery_unesting_part_1